# NoSuchElementException when using By.Xpath

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, xpath

Edit :

The element was inside an iframe, this is how it finally worked:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, 60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By
            .xpath("//*[@class='IFrameID']")));
WebElement element_t = _driver.findElement(
          By.xpath("//*[@myattribute='mytest']"));
```

---

Edit :

My problem seems to be the structure of the page. i tried different things, and i only was able to get the body by id, ever other element i tried to get by id or any other attribute couldnt be found...

---

I am trying to get an element by using the By.xpath method, the xpath itself works just fine when used in firebug/firepath, but when used in the java application i am getting an Exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:    {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@myattribute='mytest']"}
```

The attribute i am trying to access is not a standard html one, but generated from a framework so the field looks like this :

```
<input id="F_19" class="FIELDInputEdit" type="text" style=" width:100%;" maxlength="40" myattribute="mytest" name="CC">
```

The javacode itself looks like this :

```
WebElement element_t = _driver.findElement(
          By.xpath(".//*[@myattribute='mytest']"));
```

Since the only known attribute is this one, i have no ohter way to access the input field.
I am using Firefox 17.0.11

Comment: I see a typo: `myattribut` vs `myattribute`. Is this from copying to here, or the actual issue?

Comment: just from copying ... sry

Comment: Have you tried adding a wait for element? It could be that selenium looks for it right after the page has loaded but before the browser javascript has added it to the page.

Comment: i tried now with no effect: `WebElement element_t = (new WebDriverWait(_driver, 10))
   .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
     By.xpath(".//*[@myattribute='mytest']")));`

Comment: Is the element you are looking for inside an iFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element was inside an iframe, this is how it finally worked:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, 60);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By
        .xpath("//*[@class='IFrameID']")));
WebElement element_t = _driver.findElement(
      By.xpath("//*[@myattribute='mytest']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

good practice (imho) before using xpath in webdriver test it using selenium ide (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Error might be because of «.» before «//». Try to remove it.

Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

`.//*[@myattribute='mytest']`

«.» = Selects the current node

«//» = Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are

«*» = Matches any element node

«[@myattribute='mytest']» ( = [@myattribute = \"mytest\"]) = Node, that contains attribute "myattribute", which value is "mytest"

Now, `_driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@myattribute='mytest']"))` = search whole page for first node with attribute «myattribute» with value «mytest»

```
_driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@myattribute='mytest']"))
```

= search whole page for first input with «myattribute» = «mytest»

`_driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@myattribute='mytest']")).then(By.path("./*[@comeAtr]"))` = in input with «myattribute» = «mytest» find any node with atribute = «

Comment: Imean there should me findAll method. You can try to look for List<WebElement> webElements = driver.findAll(By.xpath("//input[@id]")) And use breakpoint to check if this element exist (find it on page, locate id value, look this value in ide)

Comment: I sadly can not use the ID since its generated and not known. All I have to go on is this attribute.

Comment: i tried all of the suggested variations in firepath AND from java, all of them work in firepath, none of them from java............ Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@myattribute='mytest']"}
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//input[@myattribute='mytest']"}
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@myattribute='mytest']"}
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@myattribute='mytest']"}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use CSS selectors instead?

```
By.cssSelector("input[myattribute=\"mytest\"]")
```